# Caching a LINQ to SQL DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We're in the process of doing some performance optimization for a multi-tenant Web application.  Currently, a LinqToSql Data Context is created at the beginning of each web request.  The context has a lifetime for the web request and it's injected into the constructor of any objects that need it using Castle Windsor.

We had the thought of caching the context (and a set of objects attached to it) in the session cache for up to a few minutes to optimize the setup costs for follow-on web requests.  Is this a good/bad idea?  What issues need to be considered?

Comment: Have you examined every query that is run through the datacontext to ensure a minimum of database IO is consumed?  Have you examined the callers of the datacontext to make sure repeated fetches for the same data is not occuring?

Comment: @David: tuning the queries that show up as hot spots in the profiler.  our repository implementation protects against repeated fetches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bad idea IMO. The biggest problem would be concurrency. Thanks to connection-pooling, the costs aren't that much as long as you use the data-context as a *pipe* for data, not the data bucket itself.

Cache the *data*; throw away the data-context.

Attempting to hold onto the data-context *additionally* doesn't scale out to multiple servers, or support any cache implementation except in-process.

Have you *measured* the setup costs so that you know whether this is worth considering? I really don't believe that is your bottleneck.

Comment: We've measured.  It's not the creation of the dc that's the issue, it's the data attached.  Our initial thought was along your lines and we would definitely just re-attach if it were a greenfield development scenario.  Before we refactor to rehydrate the context, we want to understand what actually could go wrong if we just leave the dc intact over a short timespan.

Comment: @Rob - you shouldn't *need* data in your data-context. It is not *meant* to be used as a data store (even *with* the identity-manager). Personally, I would move that data *out* of the data-context; use the data-context to **get** it, but cache it externally.

Comment: @Mark - agreed.  In a greenfield scenario, that's how we would approach it.  The existing repositories are written so that they assume the entities are in the change set, so we would have to rehydrate the context from the cache.  Certainly not impossible, and it's likely that's what we'll do, but we want to understand all the issues before we spend limited dev time there.